# Yolov7 - Pytorch to TensorRT not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)

Tags: python, pytorch, yolo, tensorrt

I'm trying to use Yolov7 with TensorRT following the `colab` you mentioned in the Yolov7 documentation

https://colab.research.google.com/gist/AlexeyAB/fcb47ae544cf284eb24d8ad8e880d45c/yolov7trtlinaom.ipynb

```
YOLOR  2022-11-25 torch 1.13.0+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti, 8191.5MB)
```

I exported the file the engine file `yolov7-tiny-nms.trt` successfully without any problems

```
Successfully exported: Serializing engine to file: /content/tensorrt-python/yolov7-tiny-nms.trt
```

When I try to run the following code

```
pred = BaseEngine(engine_path='/content/tensorrt-python/yolov7-tiny-nms.trt')
origin_img = pred.inference('/content/yolov7/inference/images/horses.jpg')
```

I got this error

```
d:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7\myBuild.py:31: DeprecationWarning: Use get_tensor_shape instead.
  size = trt.volume(engine.get_binding_shape(binding))
d:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7\myBuild.py:32: DeprecationWarning: Use get_tensor_dtype instead.
  dtype = trt.nptype(engine.get_binding_dtype(binding))
d:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7\myBuild.py:36: DeprecationWarning: Use get_tensor_mode instead.
  if engine.binding_is_input(binding):
PS D:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7>
```

The error explains it selfs so I used `get_tensor_shape` and `get_tensor_dtype`  and `get_tensor_mode`  instead of the `get_binding_shape` and `get_binding_dtype` and `binding_is_input`

The error goes away!

Now when I try to run the same code which is

```
pred = BaseEngine(engine_path='/content/tensorrt-python/yolov7-tiny-nms.trt')
origin_img = pred.inference('/content/yolov7/inference/images/horses.jpg')
```

I got a different error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7\myBuild.py", line 228, in <module>
    origin_img = pred.inference('./horses.jpg')
  File "d:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7\myBuild.py", line 63, in inference
    num, final_boxes, final_scores, final_cls_inds = self.infer(img)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 0)
PS D:\projects\build-tenssor\yolov7>
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

The score code

```
    def inference(self, img_path, conf=0.25):
        origin_img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        origin_img = cv2.cvtColor(origin_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img, ratio = preproc(origin_img, self.imgsz, self.mean, self.std)
        num, final_boxes, final_scores, final_cls_inds = self.infer(img)
        final_boxes = np.reshape(final_boxes, (-1, 4))
        num = num[0]
        if num >0:
            final_boxes, final_scores, final_cls_inds = final_boxes[:num]/ratio, final_scores[:num], final_cls_inds[:num]
            origin_img = vis(origin_img, final_boxes, final_scores, final_cls_inds,
                             conf=conf, class_names=self.class_names)
        origin_img = cv2.cvtColor(origin_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)                      
        return origin_img
```

You can find the source code at the bottom of this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/AlexeyAB/fcb47ae544cf284eb24d8ad8e880d45c/yolov7trtlinaom.ipynb#scrollTo=fpbjz0ao_kyF) page
https://colab.research.google.com/gist/AlexeyAB/fcb47ae544cf284eb24d8ad8e880d45c/yolov7trtlinaom.ipynb#scrollTo=fpbjz0ao_kyF

Thanks

I've tried to run it on colap it works but not on my environment

Comment: Could you please share your environment TensorRT version ?

import tensorrt as trt;
print(trt.__version__)

Comment: @MaxD. TensorRT-8.5.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `--include-nms` with `--end2end` in argument to export onnx model command as shown below.

```
!python export.py --weights ./yolov7-tiny.pt --grid --simplify --end2end
```